# Why is SQL Server 2008 index maintenance run only for indexes with index_level set to 0?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I have been using an index defrag script from `sqlfool.com` for SQL server that I modify to work within our overnight maintenance procedures. The script is a work in progress that is modified when bugs are found or when improvements can be added. What I like about the script is that there are many people using it and a lot of thought has gone into it.

The latest version can be found here http://sqlfool.com/ about half way down the page.

There is a part of the script that I am not sure about and have tried to track down some info on it but can’t seem to get a definitive answer as to why it was done that way.

Below is the part of the script that is used to decide which indexes should be considered for rebuilding or reorganizing. I have also included the parameters that are passed in to the procedure that are relevant to the decision made in the insert.

```
@minFragmentation       FLOAT               = 10.0  
    /* in percent, will not defrag if fragmentation less than specified */

, @minPageCount           INT                 = 8 
    /*  MS recommends > 1 extent (8 pages) */

, @scanMode               VARCHAR(10)         = N'LIMITED'
    /* Options are LIMITED, SAMPLED, and DETAILED */

INSERT INTO dbo.dba_indexDefragStatus
(
      databaseID
    , databaseName
    , objectID
    , indexID
    , partitionNumber
    , fragmentation
    , page_count
    , range_scan_count
    , scanDate
)
SELECT
      ps.database_id AS 'databaseID'
    , QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(ps.database_id)) AS 'databaseName'
    , ps.[object_id] AS 'objectID'
    , ps.index_id AS 'indexID'
    , ps.partition_number AS 'partitionNumber'
    , SUM(ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent) AS 'fragmentation'
    , SUM(ps.page_count) AS 'page_count'
    , os.range_scan_count
    , GETDATE() AS 'scanDate'
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(@databaseID, OBJECT_ID(@tableName), NULL , NULL, @scanMode) AS ps
JOIN sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(@databaseID, OBJECT_ID(@tableName), NULL , NULL) AS os
    ON ps.database_id = os.database_id
    AND ps.[object_id] = os.[object_id]
    AND ps.index_id = os.index_id
    AND ps.partition_number = os.partition_number
WHERE avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= @minFragmentation 
    AND ps.index_id > 0 -- ignore heaps
    AND ps.page_count > @minPageCount 
    AND ps.index_level = 0 -- leaf-level nodes only, supports @scanMode
GROUP BY ps.database_id 
    , QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(ps.database_id)) 
    , ps.[object_id]
    , ps.index_id 
    , ps.partition_number 
    , os.range_scan_count
OPTION (MAXDOP 2);
```

What I would like to know is why the is the filter below in there where clause?

```
AND ps.index_level = 0 -- leaf-level nodes only, supports @scanMode
```

Below is the result of one of the indexes and it shows that the index level one is at 99% average fragmentation.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just e-mail Michelle Ufford @sqlfool.com and ask her directly?

Answer (score 1):

In your reference picture index_level 1, and index_level 2 have a page count of under 1,000.

Since there are very little pages in those index level, the fragmentation percentage is irrelevant to performance, it would be a superficial impact to have them less.

References:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966523.aspx

> Generally, you should not be concerned with fragmentation levels of indexes with less than 1,000 pages. In the tests, indexes containing more than 10,000 pages realized performance gains, with the biggest gains on indexes with significantly more pages (greater than 50,000 pages).